# How to make simple to use logger for C++ classes

Tags: c++, qt

I created a logger class, derived it to to other classes in order to have easy function access eg. log(txt) error(txt)  etc. but i use text to add prefix to logger and also color parameters.

All derived logger classes have vectors of string for data filtering purposes and extern class where the info gets sent about new log entries.

Currently ran into multiple inheritance issues, due to 2 derived classes inheriting and trying to initialize logger with dif prefix.

Is there a way to have simple to call and to define logger but not run into derived class issues?

**logger.h**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include "qstring.h"
#include "vector"

using namespace std;


class logger
{

    public:
    void log(QString txt);
    void error(QString txt);

    logger(){

    }

    logger(QString logPrefix,QString color_="")
    {
       loggerAddPrefixAndSetColor(logPrefix,color_);
    }

    void loggerAddPrefixAndSetColor(QString logPrefix,QString color_="")
    {
        prefix+=logPrefix+":";
        loggerSetColor(color_);
    }

    void loggerSetColor(QString color_=""){
        if(!color_.isEmpty())
        color=color_;
    }




private:

    int id=-1;
    void getId();


    QString color;
    QString prefix="";
    vector<QString>logHistory;
    vector<QString>errorHistory;

};

#endif // LOGGER_H
```

**logger .cpp**

```
#include "logger.h"
#include "logManager.h"
#include "htmlMacros.hpp"




void logger::getId()
{
    id=  LOG_MANAGER.getNextLoggerId(this);
}

void logger::log(QString txt)
{

    if(color.isEmpty())
        errorHistory.emplace_back( prefix + txt);
    else
        errorHistory.emplace_back(color + prefix + txt + html::Span);

   LOG_MANAGER.newLogEntry(id);

}

 void logger::error(QString txt)
{

    logHistory.push_back(html::BackgroundDarkRed + html::ColorWhite + prefix + txt + html::Span + html::Span);
    LOG_MANAGER.newErrorEntry(id);
}
```

**log manager.h**

```
#ifndef LOGMANAGER_H
#define LOGMANAGER_H
#include <qdatetime.h>
#include <vector>
//#include "logger.h"

using namespace std;

class logger;

class logManager
{
public:
    logManager();


    qint64 lastLogMsgTimeMsEpoch=0;
    qint64 lastTimePrintTimeMsEpoch=0;

    QString getLogText(QString info, bool showMsDif=0);



    int getNextLoggerId(logger*ptr){
        int id=loggers.size();
        loggers.emplace_back(ptr);
        return id;
    }
    vector<logger*>loggers;

    void newLogEntry(int id){
        //todo
    }

    void newErrorEntry(int id){

    }


    //nb add func to log to file / tcp etc but in parralel task to not slow executuon?

}extern LOG_MANAGER;
#endif // LOGMANAGER_H
```

**log manager .cpp**

```
#include "logManager.h"
#include "htmlMacros.hpp"
#include "../usual/convert.h"

logManager LOG_MANAGER;

logManager::logManager()
{
    lastLogMsgTimeMsEpoch=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
}

QString logManager::getLogText(QString info,bool showMsDif)
{


    qint64 msTime=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();


    QString infoOut;
    qint64 difToLastPrint = msTime - lastTimePrintTimeMsEpoch ;
    if(difToLastPrint > 1000){
        QDateTime dateTime=QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        infoOut+= (html::ColorCyan + dateTime.toString("yyyy.MM.dd - HH:mm:ss")+html::Span +"<br>");
        lastTimePrintTimeMsEpoch=msTime;
    }

    infoOut+=info;



    if(showMsDif){

        qint64 msDif=msTime-lastLogMsgTimeMsEpoch;

        if(msDif>0)
        infoOut+=" - "+html::ColorYellow+n(msDif)+"ms"+html::Span;
    }


    lastLogMsgTimeMsEpoch=msTime;

    return infoOut;
}
```

**Usage problem scenario ,might be pseudocode**

```
    class c1 : public logger{

c1():logger("c1 log"){}

};

    class c2 : public c1, logger{ 

c2():logger("c2 log"){}

};
```

Goal is to have usage as simple like log("txt") not log.log("txt") or log("caller class:txt") without inheritance conflicts while keeping the ability of specializing colors and prefix?

Comment: Why do you do any kind of inheritance after a `logger`? This looks like [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Consider using some external library for logging purposes. Qt (you have a tag of it) has already something build in.

Comment: In your example, `c1` is already a logger, and `c2` derived from it. If the problem is in the prefix, set the new prefix in `c2` constructor, i.e. `class c2 : public c1 { public: c2() { setPrefix("c2 log");} ...};`

Comment: do you really need to derive from `logger`? seems like a strange thing to do, shouldn't `c1` and `c2` just have a `logger` member variables?

Comment: "do you really need to derive from logger? seems like a strange thing to do, shouldn't c1 and c2 just have a logger member variables?"
How to separate prefixes for each class while keeping easy usage?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what this logger should do (why you think inheritance is needed). Usually there is only one logger for the whole application (quite often represented as a singleton).

Comment: `"Please edit your question and describe what this logger should do (why you think inheritance is needed). Usually there is only one logger for the whole application (quite often represented as a singleton)."` @Marek R
It may not be needed if its possible without to have caller class identified and named while usage is simple like `log("txt")` not `log.log("txt")` or  `log("caller class:txt")`.

Comment: Qt built in logger is the best choice for Qt user, what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare on Global Static function that encompasses log routine and use that function every where...

for.eg.

```
static void QLOG( char * fmt, ... )
{
    va_list l;
    va_start(l, fmt);

    Logger->log(fmt);

    va_end(l);
}
```

Comment: Does this solution keep caller class specific prefixes?

Comment: you can modify it to include prefixes, should be easy.

static void QLOG( PREFIX, char * fmt, ... )

Comment: Idea is to write class specific prefix once , not every time new log entry is added.

Comment: what kind of prefixes are you planning to use, generally it is WARNING, ERROR, INFO and MESSAGE and so on.

Comment: `what kind of prefixes are you planning to use, generally it is WARNING, ERROR, INFO and MESSAGE and so on`   So far idea is to have class name and where it is used, for example serialization class could be used in networking or serial port etc. Would be useful to log prefixes to get better idea where error occured.

Comment: Is this not possible with C++?